# C# Search Textfile after multiple Datas and fill them into a Datagrid View

Tags: c#

I get the datas from an textfile. The File itself is already inserted by `ReadAllLines` and converted into a string - this works fine for me and I checked the content with a MessageBox.

The Textfile looks like this (This is just 1 line from about thousand):

```
3016XY1234567891111111ABCDEFGHIJKabcdef+0000001029916XY1111111123456789ABCDEFGHIJKabcdef+00000003801
```

Now these are 2 records and I need 2 datas from every record.

1. The "XY Number" - these are the first 16 digits AFTER "16XY" (16XY is always the same value)

   ```
      Value from the example: XY1234567891111111
   ```
2. The "Price" - that is the 11 digits value after the plus. The last 2 digits specify the amount of Cent.

   ```
      Value from the example: 102,99$
   ```

I Need both of this datas to be in the same row in my Datagrid View and also for all other Datas in this textfile.

All I can imagine is to write a code, which searchs the string after "16XY" and counts the next 16 digits - the same with the Price which searchs for a "plus" and counts the next 11 digits. Just in this case I would need to ignore the first line of the file because there are about 10x"+".

I tried several possibilities to search and count for that values but without any success right now. Im also not sure how to get the datas into the specific Datagrid View.

This is all I have to show at the moment:

```
List<List<string>> groups = new List<List<string>>();
                    List<string> current = null;
                    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
                    {
                        if (line.Contains("") && current == null)
                            current = new List<string>();                              
                        else if (line.Contains("") && current != null)
                        {
                            groups.Add(current);
                            current = null;
                        }
                        if (current != null)
                            current.Add(line);
                    }

                //array

                string output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, current.ToArray());

                //string

                string final = string.Join("", output.ToCharArray());
                MessageBox.Show(output);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the text file use newlines to define separate rows, i.e. does File.ReadAllLines(...) return an array of strings, or is it just a single giant string?  Also, in the example, there are 2 sets of the XYNumber and Price pairs, is it always 2 pairs per line?

Comment: Its a single giant string. Its random how much pairs per line are shown - this automated system is about 15 years old.. it appears that there are 5 pairs per line, sometimes 8-10, sometimes also splitted (that the price for example just shows up in the next line)

Answer (score 2):

Create a `class` or `struct` to hold data

```
public class Data
{
    String XYValue { set; get; }
    Decimal Price { set; get; }
}
```

Then the reading logic **(You might need to add some more checks)**:

```
string decimalSeperator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
List<Data> results = new List<Data>();
foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1))
{
    if (line == null)
        continue;

    int indexOfNextXY = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        int indexOfXY = line.IndexOf("16XY", indexOfNextXY) + "16XY".Length;
        int indexOfPlus = line.IndexOf("+", indexOfXY + 16) + "+".Length;
        indexOfNextXY = line.IndexOf("16XY", indexOfPlus);

        string xyValue = line.Substring(indexOfXY - 2, 18); // -2 to get the XY part
        string price = indexOfNextXY < 0 ? line.Substring(indexOfPlus) : line.Substring(indexOfPlus, indexOfNextXY - indexOfPlus);

        string intPart = price.Substring(0, price.Length - 2);
        string decimalPart = price.Substring(price.Length - 2);
        price = intPart  + decimalSeperator + decimalPart;


        results.Add(new Data (){ XYValue = xyValue, Price = Convert.ToDecimal(price) });

        if (indexOfNextXY < 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider employing the `Split` method. From the example data, I notice there is "16XY" between each value. So something like this:

```
var data = "3016XY1234567891111111ABCDEFGHIJKabcdef+0000001029916XY1111111123456789ABCDEFGHIJKabcdef+00000003801";

var records = data.Split(new string[] { "16XY" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Given the example data this will return the following array:

```
[0]: "30"
[1]: "1234567891111111ABCDEFGHIJKabcdef+00000010299"
[2]: "1111111123456789ABCDEFGHIJKabcdef+00000003801"
```

Now it will be easier to count characters in each string and give them meaning in your code.

So we know valuable data is separated by **+**. Lets split it further and fill a `Dictionary<string, double>`.

```
var parsed = new Dictionary<string, double>(records.Length - 1);

foreach (var pairX in records.Skip(1))
{
    var fields = pairX.Split('+');
    var cents = double.Parse(fields[1]);
    parsed.Add(fields[0], cents / 100);
}

// Now you bind to the GridView
gv.DataSource = parsed;
```

And your 'GridView` declaration should look like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Key" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="Price" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Runs through without error but the datagrid remains empty :(

Comment: My fault! I forgot to change the "XY" into the actual datas which I can't publish here. Now getting the error "Index was outside the bounds of the array." regarding the line `var cents = double.Parse(fields[1]);`

Comment: It means it failed to split by **+**. Is it present in your real data? This code runing fine at my side...

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\+(\d+)(\d{2})16(XY\d{16})");
var q =
    from e in File.ReadLines("123.txt")
    let find = regex.Match(e)
    where find.Success
    select new
    {
        price = double.Parse(find.Groups[1].Value) + (double.Parse(find.Groups[2].Value) / 100),
        value = find.Groups[3]
    };

dataGridView1.DataSource = q.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the whole text file as string, you can manipulate it with `.Split` method.

The action will look something like this:

```
var values = final.Split(new string[] { "16XY" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

List <YourModel> models = new List<YourModel>();

foreach (var item in values)
{
      if (item.IndexOf('+') > 0)
      {
            var itemSplit = item.Split('+');
            if (itemSplit[0].Length > 15 &&
                itemSplit[1].Length > 10)
            {
                 models.Add(new YourModel(itemSplit[0].Substring(0, 16), itemSplit[1].Substring(0, 11)));
            }
      }
}
```

And you will need some model

```
public class YourModel
{
    public YourModel(string xy, string price)
    {
        float forTest = 0;
        XYNUMBER = xy;

        string addForParse = string.Format("{0}.{1}", price.Substring(0, price.Length - 2), price.Substring(price.Length - 2, 2));

        if (float.TryParse(addForParse, out forTest)) 
        {
            Price = forTest;
        }
    }

    public string XYNUMBER { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

After that you can bind it to your gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the "data pairs" are variable each line (and can get truncated to the next line), it is best to use File.ReadAllText() instead.  This will give you a single string to work on, eliminating the truncation issue.

```
var data = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Define a model to contain your data:

```
public class Item {
  public string XYNumber { get; set; }
  public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use regular expressions to find matches and store them in a list:

```
var list = List<Item>();
var regex = new Regex(@"(XY\d{16})\w+\+(\d{11})");
var match = regex.Match(data);
while (match.Success) {
  var ps = match.Group[1].Captures[0].Value.Insert(9, ".");
  list.Add(new Item { 
    XYNumber = match.Group[0].Captures[0].Value,
    Price = Convert.ToDouble(ps)
  });
  match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

The list can also be used as a data source to a grid view:

```
gridView.DataSource = list;
```